# On separable field extensions

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields

Let $F\subseteq K$ be a finite separable field extension with $a_1,..., a_n$ an $F$-basis for $K$. Is it true that the matrix $A := [\mbox{tr}(a_ia_j)]$ is non-singular ?

Comment: This is one of separability's many definitions. See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a basic result on discriminants. Let $d=\det A$, and let $L$ be an algebraically closed field containing $F$, with $\tau_1,\dots,\tau_n$ the $F$-embeddings of $K$ into $L$. First note that $d=\det(\tau_i(a_j))^2$. If $d=0$, there exist $x_1,\dots,x_n\in L$, at least one of which is non-zero, such that $\sum x_i\tau_i(a_j) = 0$ for all $j$, and thus $\sum x_i \tau_i(y) = 0$ for all $y\in K$, contradicting linear independence of characters.

Comment: Would you explain the second line more or give me a reference !?

Comment: There are $n$ distinct $F$-embeddings $K\hookrightarrow L$ since $K/F$ is separable. The expression for $d$ in terms of embeddings is a straightforward computation: $d=\det(\textrm{tr}(a_j a_k))=\det(\sum_i \tau_i(a_j a_k)) = \det(\sum_i \tau_i(a_j) \tau_i(a_k)) = \det(\tau_i(a_j))\det(\tau_i(a_k))=\det(\tau_i(a_j))^2.$